# how to make an html button do something with razor

Tags: asp.net, razor

```
<input onclick="SignOut" class="button" type="button" value="Sign Out">
```

What do I need to do with razor to let the button do something on click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change type to "submit"

```
<input onclick="SignOut" class="button" type="submit" value="Sign Out">
```

Comment: thanks for the help. what I want to do is if button is clicked go to test.cshtml how can I do that.

Comment: Did you make like this onclick="location.href='test.cshtml'" ?